# AutoHotKey: SetTitleMatchMode mysteriously set to 1

Tags: autohotkey

Today in my master AutoHotKey script all the application-specific hotstrings and hotkeys mysteriously stopped working. After a lot of debugging, I discovered that SetTitleMatchMode had been set to 1 in the background...even though I never explicitly do this in my code.
So, all my directives like...

```
#IfWinActive Some Window Substring
```

...weren't working anymore.

The line of code

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
```

is already in the code, and didn't fix the issue.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

My current hypothesis is that the statement

```
#Include SomeOtherScript.ahk
```

Automatically Sets Title Match Mode to 1, unless 'SomeOtherScript.ahk' explicitly has a statement that that will do SetTitleMatchMode to some other value.
But it's a weak hypothesis. The Include statement has been in there for a long time.

Comment: What other changes did you make? `SetTitleMatchMode, 2` needs to be in the auto execute section. Included file can end the auto execute section with a `return` or call `SetTitleMatchMode`. The `#Include` statement doesn't do anything to title match mode by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Like Oleg said in your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329896/autohotkey-settitlematchmode-mysteriously-set-to-1#comment79634165_46329896), your `SetTitleMatchMode 2` needs to execute to have any effect, and if it's not near the top of your script it may not be in the autoexecute section.

Problems like this are usually straightforward to troubleshoot by  adding some temporary logging:

```
...

SetTitleMatchMode 2
MsgBox DEBUG1 SetTitleMatch is %A_TitleMatchMode%

... some code ...

MsgBox DEBUG2 SetTitleMatch is %A_TitleMatchMode%

... some more code ...

MsgBox DEBUG3a SetTitleMatch is %A_TitleMatchMode%
#Include SomeOtherScript.ahk
MsgBox DEBUG3b SetTitleMatch is %A_TitleMatchMode%
```

You can also check for unexpected or forgotten `SetTitleMatch` statements buried in your code by searching your folders using a search tool like `grep`:

```
C:\> grep -iR SetTitleMatch .
```

A third option is to try a divide-and-conquer approach to isolate code that's causing the problem.  Save your work, then delete half your code and see if the problem is still occurs. If it is still misbehaving, delete half the remaining code, and check again.  If the problem is fixed by removing some code, *add* back half the deleted code and check again. Eventually and with a little luck, you'll isolate and identify the statements causing the problem

Comment: +1 for your divide-and-conquer approach. In Autohotkey an innocent looking statement might affect something completely unrelated in a completely different part of the script so it might be necessary.

Comment: Jim U: The ability to access the value of TitleMatchMode via %A_TitleMatchMode% was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You nailed it. your suggestion, combined with Oleg's comments about the auto execute section, helped me find the root cause: It turns out that I added a statement to the Include program that ended the auto execute section. Since my SetTitleMatchMode statement was after the include statement, that small change to the include program meant that my SetTitleMatchMode statement was never recognized.